# Upload multiple camera photos with html input

Tags: html, file-upload

I have a web application with an upload form.

```
<input type="file" name="c_files[]" id="c_files" multiple="multiple" />
```

I can select and upload mutliple files from the gallery but can't make multiple photos from the camera app. Taking the photos first and then uploading them from the gallery is not a good way to go.

I'm using Google Chrome Version 92.0.4515.159 on Android 11.
Firefox for Android and Safari on iOS isn't working either.

Apparently I have to use javascript right or is their an exisiting work around?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "Out of the Box" that will solve your problem or your scenario, and the truth is that not HTML have at least one way to get there.

But... we have javascript I can think of something that is not exactly what you are looking for but it would be the way to perform this feat:

1. detect that you are on a mobile device.
2. allow that if you are on a mobile device when you click on the file field, you directly invoke the camera APP and take multiple photos.
3. when returning to the form detect the event and make the programmatic trigger of the multiple input type file, but directly open the image gallery...
4. select multiple images to attach.

As you can see, this is a concept/solution based on the capabilities that we know the mobile environment and the javascript language have. regardless of HTML.

To achieve this you must get each point mentioned above to work.